# safari web inspector preview not accurate

Tags: safari-web-inspector

I am trying to make a simple web site look ok on iphone 6 ... when I preview it in Safari web inspector it looks fine:

[Preview of site for iphone 6 in Safari web inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKxv7.png)

However, when I actually open the live site on my iphone, it looks like this:

[actual site on iphone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVKQe.png)

If I have to, I can keep (blindly) tweaking it and uploading the new css file to the web, and checking it until I fix the spacing problem, but does anyone know why the preview isn't accurate?

Comment: I just realized that the preview available is of iphone6s. I have an iphone6, but not 6s. Maybe this is the problem? the preview I am looking at is at 375 by 667 px.

Comment: Are you using Responsive Design Mode? If so, this is unexpected and you should file a bug report (https://bugreport.apple.com).